# Technologies Textbox Width Too Small?

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

When entering what technologies I studied during my BS degree program, I found that I couldn't  place the ten technologies I wanted in the textbox because I reached the character limit of the textbox.

Should the character limit for the textbox be larger?

Or am I over-qualifying the terms I'm using (object-oriented-design, for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be over-qualifying :)  You can't over-over-qualify though because our maximum tag length is 25 (we just truncate anything after that).

Seeing as you get 10 technologies at 25 characters a piece the length for that field should have been 259 but it was set at 150.  It's fixed now.

Comment: Thanks Jason! I think those limits work! It hadn't even occurred to me that there a character limit for the tags themselves, but it makes sense that there is!

Comment: @Feaelin Moilar: No Problem